# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for java.awt.event.MouseAdapter in Applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm not sure why I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError runtime error on the following line:

```
  this.startBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      startClicked();
    }
  });
```

in an Applet.  It compiles fine. How can the jre not find a core awt class?  I use the same line in a different applet without issues.  What am I not understanding?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at "[NoClassDefFoundError in Java Applet on invokeLater()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771537/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-applet-on-invokelater)". Compiling the class that contains your code snippet will produce other class files like `MyClass$1.class`. Make sure they're also deployed.

Comment: if the class isn't in the classpath, `ClassNotFoundException` should be the one thrown.

Comment: @irreputable: Not in this case. If an application were using something like `Class.forName()`, then `ClassNotFoundException` might be thrown.